# How can i load a .txt file to listbox in c#

Tags: c#

This will fix your reading problem.
Just change the string "file.txt" to the opendialog.filename

```
       using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
        {
            string line;

            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(line);
            }
            sr.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
listbox.Items.AddRange(lines);
```

I stripped the file dialog part...